# cURL and CherryPy digest authentication

Tags: json, curl, cherrypy

When using CherryPy and cURL together with digest authentication I ran apparently to the same kind of issue that is described in following question (cURL and nodeJs here):

[Curl command for digest auth using a json post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552053/curl-command-for-digest-auth-using-a-json-post#new-answer)

Does anybody know a workaround to this with CherryPY?

Comment: issue was indeed basically the same as with nodejs. So CherryPy also handles the initial authentication request via body parser. So my solution was to modify cherryPys jsontools.py   json_processor function to check if body length is zero and add empty json to cherrypy.serving.request.json.

Comment: Please file an issue at [our GItHub](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues) and we'll think of improving the code base or advise you better solution than patching the framework :)